# How can an object access variables of the class it lives in

Tags: java, swing, aggregation

I have two classes. One is my Javaswing Main class and the other a component, used in the Main class:

main.java:

```
public class main{

    static int x = 10;
    Component comp = new Component();

    //Swing Stuff...

}
```

component.java:

```
public class Component{
    int y = ...

    //Swing stuff...
}
```

Now, I'm wondering, if or how I can achieve, that y = x from the main class. The goal here is to have some global styles in the main class, which are read by all my Swing Components.

Comment: `int y = main.x;`? It is a static field so you can access it without a `main` reference.

Comment: Class names should start in uppercase, so they don't get confused with variable names, which start in lowercase.

Comment: In your example, you have to pass x to Component.   Put global styles in their own static class, and reference the styles from whichever Component needs them.

Comment: Yes, storing the styles in a seperate class seems to be a good solution. However since they're static I can't change them. How would I handle features, like a dark mode, where styles change according to a field in my Main Class?

Comment: Wouldn't a constructor do the trick? public Component(int valueForY) { this.y = valueForY;} example: https://ideone.com/e.js/w5Jzxi

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Main {
  static int x = 10;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Component component = new Component();
    System.out.println(component.y);
    System.out.println(x);

    component.y = x;
    System.out.println(component.y);
    System.out.println(x);
  }
}

class Component {
  int y = 20;
}
```

```
20
10
10
10
```